SPFx and Material React Table Error You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type (fresh installation)
I'm trying to use Material React Table in a fresh installation of SPFx created with:
yo @microsoft/sharepoint

After SPFx installation I install Material React Table with:
npm i material-react-table @mui/material @mui/x-date-pickers @mui/icons-material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

After that, I create a component that implements Material React Table, according to their page Material React Table - Basic example. My component looks like this:
import * as React from 'react';

import { useMemo } from 'react';
import {
  MaterialReactTable,
  useMaterialReactTable,
  type MRT_ColumnDef,
} from 'material-react-table';

//example data type
type Person = {
    name: {
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
    };
    address: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
};

const data: Person[] = [
    {
      name: {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
      },
      address: '261 Erdman Ford',
      city: 'East Daphne',
      state: 'Kentucky',
    },
    {
      name: {
        firstName: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Doe',
      },
      address: '769 Dominic Grove',
      city: 'Columbus',
      state: 'Ohio',
    },
    {
      name: {
        firstName: 'Joe',
        lastName: 'Doe',
      },
      address: '566 Brakus Inlet',
      city: 'South Linda',
      state: 'West Virginia',
    },
    {
      name: {
        firstName: 'Kevin',
        lastName: 'Vandy',
      },
      address: '722 Emie Stream',
      city: 'Lincoln',
      state: 'Nebraska',
    },
    {
      name: {
        firstName: 'Joshua',
        lastName: 'Rolluffs',
      },
      address: '32188 Larkin Turnpike',
      city: 'Omaha',
      state: 'Nebraska',
    },
];

export const App: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
    const columns = useMemo<MRT_ColumnDef<Person>[]>(
        () => [
          {
            accessorKey: 'name.firstName', //access nested data with dot notation
            header: 'First Name',
            size: 150,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'name.lastName',
            header: 'Last Name',
            size: 150,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'address', //normal accessorKey
            header: 'Address',
            size: 200,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'city',
            header: 'City',
            size: 150,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'state',
            header: 'State',
            size: 150,
          },
        ],
        [],
    );

    const table = useMaterialReactTable({
        columns,
        data, //data must be memoized or stable (useState, useMemo, defined outside of this component, etc.)
    });

    return (
        <MaterialReactTable table={table} />
    )
}

And after compiling the App with this component I get this error:
Error - [webpack] 'dist':
./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/utils/views.js 13:34
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:34)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   defaultViews
| }) => {
>   const viewsWithDefault = views ?? defaultViews;
|   let openToWithDefault;
|   if (openTo != null) {
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/utils/date-utils.js 1:0-40 97:6-19 100:6-19 103:6-19 106:6-19 109:6-19
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker/TimePickerToolbar.js
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

./node_modules/@tanstack/virtual-core/dist/esm/index.js 241:51
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (241:51)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     this.notify = (force, sync) => {
|       var _a, _b;
>       const { startIndex, endIndex } = this.range ?? {
|         startIndex: void 0,
|         endIndex: void 0
 @ ./node_modules/@tanstack/react-virtual/dist/esm/index.js 3:0-164 4:0-39 4:0-39 21:14-25 34:4-22 35:4-24 36:16-29 43:24-41 44:26-45 45:16-28
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker/DateTimePickerToolbar.js 247:39
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (247:39)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   const translations = usePickersTranslations();
|   const classes = useUtilityClasses(ownerState);
>   const toolbarTitle = inToolbarTitle ?? translations.dateTimePickerToolbarTitle;
|   const formatHours = time => ampm ? utils.format(time, 'hours12h') : utils.format(time, 'hours24h');
|   const dateText = React.useMemo(() => {
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker/index.js 4:0-64 4:0-64
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDateTimePicker/DesktopDateTimePickerLayout.js 27:67
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (27:67)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     classes
|   } = props;
>   const isActionBarVisible = actionBar && (actionBar.props.actions?.length ?? 0) > 0;
|   const ownerState = _extends({}, props, {
|     isRtl
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDateTimePicker/index.js 2:0-76 2:0-76
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker/DateTimePicker.js
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider/LocalizationProvider.js 32:50
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (32:50)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     utils: parentUtils,
|     localeText: parentLocaleText
>   } = React.useContext(MuiPickersAdapterContext) ?? {
|     utils: undefined,
|     localeText: undefined
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/hooks/useUtils.js 3:0-91 6:40-64
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker/TimePickerToolbar.js
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/hooks/date-helpers-hooks.js 33:47
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (33:47)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   const handleMeridiemChange = React.useCallback(mode => {
|     const timeWithMeridiem = date == null ? null : convertToMeridiem(date, mode, Boolean(ampm), utils);
>     onChange(timeWithMeridiem, selectionState ?? 'partial');
|   }, [ampm, date, onChange, selectionState, utils]);
|   return {
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker/TimePickerToolbar.js 16:0-72 141:6-21
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/MobileTimePicker/MobileTimePicker.js 37:52
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (37:52)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     seconds: renderTimeViewClock
|   }, defaultizedProps.viewRenderers);
>   const ampmInClock = defaultizedProps.ampmInClock ?? false;
|
|   // Props with the default values specific to the mobile variant
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/MobileTimePicker/index.js 1:0-54 1:0-54
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker/TimePicker.js
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/MobileDateTimePicker/MobileDateTimePicker.js 41:52
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (41:52)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     seconds: renderTimeViewClock
|   }, defaultizedProps.viewRenderers);
>   const ampmInClock = defaultizedProps.ampmInClock ?? false;
|
|   // Props with the default values specific to the mobile variant
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/MobileDateTimePicker/index.js 1:0-62 1:0-62
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker/DateTimePicker.js
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker/DesktopDatePicker.js 43:47
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (43:47)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     viewRenderers,
|     format: resolveDateFormat(utils, defaultizedProps, false),
>     yearsPerRow: defaultizedProps.yearsPerRow ?? 4,
|     slots: _extends({
|       openPickerIcon: CalendarIcon,
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker/index.js 1:0-56 1:0-56
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker/DatePicker.js
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopTimePicker/DesktopTimePicker.js 46:52
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (46:52)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     meridiem: renderTimeView
|   }, defaultizedProps.viewRenderers);
>   const ampmInClock = defaultizedProps.ampmInClock ?? true;
|   const actionBarActions = shouldRenderTimeInASingleColumn ? [] : ['accept'];
|   // Need to avoid adding the `meridiem` view when unexpected renderer is specified
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopTimePicker/index.js 1:0-56 1:0-56
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker/TimePicker.js
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/MobileDatePicker/MobileDatePicker.js 46:89
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (46:89)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     }, defaultizedProps.slots),
|     slotProps: _extends({}, defaultizedProps.slotProps, {
>       field: ownerState => _extends({}, resolveComponentProps(defaultizedProps.slotProps?.field, ownerState), extractValidationProps(defaultizedProps), {   
|         ref
|       }),
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/MobileDatePicker/index.js 1:0-54 1:0-54
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker/DatePicker.js
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDateTimePicker/DesktopDateTimePicker.js 48:71
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (48:71)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   const isTimeViewActive = isInternalTimeView(popperView);
|   return /*#__PURE__*/_jsxs(React.Fragment, {
>     children: [inViewRenderers[!isTimeViewActive ? popperView : 'day']?.(_extends({}, rendererProps, {
|       view: !isTimeViewActive ? popperView : 'day',
|       focusedView: focusedView && isDatePickerView(focusedView) ? focusedView : null,
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDateTimePicker/index.js 1:0-64 1:0-64
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker/DateTimePicker.js
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/material-react-table/dist/index.esm.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/App.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/components/TestTablaMui.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/testTablaMui/TestTablaMuiWebPart.js

This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "test-tabla-mui-spfx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.13.0 <17.0.0 || >=18.17.1 <19.0.0"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.106.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-component-base": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.18.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.16.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.16.6",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^7.12.0",
    "material-react-table": "^2.13.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "tslib": "2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.7": "0.1.0",
    "@rushstack/eslint-config": "2.5.1",
    "@microsoft/eslint-plugin-spfx": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/eslint-config-spfx": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.18.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "~1.15.2",
    "ajv": "^6.12.5",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.7.4",
    "@types/react": "17.0.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.17",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.18.2"
  }
}

Where is the error? How can I use Material React Table with SPFx?
Thanks in advance!
